# Toggle red / green diff on edits

Tags: feature-request

I just came across an edit, specifically [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12638502) where the edit happened because of poor default highlighting. So the only real edit is adding

```
<!-- language-all: lang-none -->
```

to the top of the code block. Unfortunately, when switching to the generated markdown tab, you still cannot see what the syntax highlighter is actually doing with the code block.

[image]

is all that is seen. This makes it difficult (impossible?) to tell how the edit will actually affect the code block.

Would it be possible to have a checkbox or something somewhere on the review page that allows you to toggle the diff colouring?

(For reference the actual "before" and "after" as rendered on the site are below)

[image]

Comment: [FYI] You can always switch to markdown view to see those kinds of changes.  See [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IlTUM.png)

Comment: @NathanOliver - that doesn't show you what the effect of that line actually is.

Comment: @MartinSmith I really need to read the question better.  This sounds nice to have.

Comment: In situations like [this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AtZjF.png) it would be a huge help. (Feel free to use this pic, BTW.)

Comment: The current workaround is to manually compare the current post in one tab with the Improve Edit version in another. This is rather clumsy.

Comment: And this is why, boys and girls, markdown should be the preferred diff.

Comment: @Braiam Have you read any of the preceding comments before adding yours?

Comment: @MartinSmith well, obviously it wasn't enough :P

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For the time being, I created a user script that adds a toggle:

[image: Revision diff color toggle example]

---

[You can find the user script here on StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/6930/show-revision-diff-color-toggle).

Comment: This script does work to remove the red /green diff colours. Unfortunately, at  least on the suggested edits page, the page does not seem to colourize the code blocks, which still makes it hard to tell in this case how the code block will be rendered differently.